Froze during Ubuntu installation now in BIOS "Unable to mount root fs"
I started an upgrade today (24, I think), and I thought that I had turned off the lock screen feature, but turns out it locked anyway. There is no box for me to put in my authentication password. I haven't done any troubleshooting yet so that I don't do any unintended damage. Help please, I am not at all tech savy.  A friend of mine originally installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Flex laptop 2.5 years ago), and I have been using it minimally, but I do need this laptop to work. My screen shows a mountain background, with no programs/apps, it's usually what I see when I'm supposed to enter in my password after it's been locked.  I tried, ctrl-alt-delete, esc, every FN. the mouse had been movable, but now is frozen.
Update: Powered off, then on. Gray screen, keyboard lit, no logo of any sort appeared on screen
Update 2: I restarted again and this time the Lenovo logo showed! it currently is in black screen with top says wn-block(0,0). last line says, [end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown -block (0,0)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Honestly it sounds to me like you might have messed up the root partition. But I'm also wondering if it's just a grub config thing. I don't remember what keys you have to press but I know there's a shell you can get into from grub. Might have to wait for more knowledgeable people to show up and reply.
